# How to group the result of a query based on the parameter value

Tags: mysql

How we can group the result of the query depending up on the parameter passed.

A small stored procedure is shown below. parameter Param is passed to the procedure.

If param value is "f" the result must  group by starttime otherwise by using formid. How can i do this. ???I tried the code show below but its not working .

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Test;
CREATE PROCEDURE Test (Param VARCHAR (2))


 BEGIN
  SELECT formid, starttime
    FROM tbevaluationscoreinfo
   CASE Param
     when 'F'
      then group by starttime;
     else
      group by formid;

   end
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to move branching up a level:

```
IF Param = 'F' THEN
  SELECT starttime, count(formid)
  FROM tbevaluationscoreinfo
  GROUP BY starttime;
ELSE
  SELECT formid, count(starttime)
  FROM tbevaluationscoreinfo
  GROUP BY formid;
END IF;
```

Another, less recommended solution, is dynamic SQL.

And the third possible solution is:

```
SELECT
  case Param when 'F' then starttime else formid end as group_column,
  count(formid),
  count(starttime)
FROM
  tbevaluationscoreinfo
GROUP BY
  group_column;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually my original stored procedure is very big.The stored procedure i wrote in the question is just a template.  So branching the query using if makes my procedure too big in size.Is this is the only way ? then i forced to do it :(

Comment: @Null Pointer, please try the third solution. Unfortunately I can't test it at the moment, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Null Pointer, Thanks! I edited the answer, is that what you meant?